# Curl showing gzip but chrome showing no gzip header

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, curl, gzip, google-pagespeed

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' https://example.com/a.min.js


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2017 02:45:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5430
Connection: keep-alive
X-Accel-Version: 0.01
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Jan 2017 12:50:18 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Cache-Control: max-age=2628000, private
```

Here it is very clear that file is gzipped but in case of chrome, pagespeed and gtmetrix they are mentioning this file is not compressed.
There is no content encoding in header when i view in chrome.

Also my homepage is being compressed with gzipp. when using `varvy` service they are saying your local files are not compressed.

I have enabled compression in nginx and apache both. also in .htaccess. but this is very weired.

Comment: Same here, and no solution! :(

Answer (score 1):

I just faced similar problem and found it was the antivirus extracting the gzipped assets.

I had to completely disable the antivirus and restart the browser.

See as well [X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network in Response Header but not Content-Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391816/x-content-encoding-over-network-in-response-header-but-not-content-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with caching.

If I had to guess, I'd say each curl request grabs a fresh response from the server with gzip encoding. Chrome on the other hand, utilizes caching which seems to store the file after decompressing it. Chrome then serves you the decompressed file (no gzip encoding) from cache.

I ran into a similar problem with chrome dev tools, and noticed that the content-encoding header was included only when I disabled caching (or hard refreshed)

[This forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115962/why-does-disable-cache-in-chrome-developer-tools-change-the-content-encoding) goes a little more in-depth about it