# json response is not compressed in express

Tags: node.js, express, compression

I use compression library to compress all my express responses. Unfortunately, it appears that none of the reponses are compressed. Yet, I specify an accept-encoding: "gzip" in the client call header. Here is the code:

front:

```js
export const api = ax.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  timeout: 1000,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  }
});

const contact = () => {
    api.get("/contact")
    .then(res=> console.log("contact response", res))
    .catch(err=> console.log("contact err", err))
  }
```

back:

```js
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");
const compression = require("compression")

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: ["http://localhost:3000"] }));
app.use(compression());


app.get('/contact',  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({hello: "world"})
  })
```

In chrome network tab, I don't have the content-encoding: gzip. How to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your anti-virus isn't using an HTTP Scanner
More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391816/x-content-encoding-over-network-in-response-header-but-not-content-encoding

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308588/10030693

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, but this question has already been answered in March 24, 2021 at 16:38. We are now February, 1st, 2023.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default threshold for compression is 1kb ([Source](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/88ba108ccebd131f336b7a0fa310f50bcc982992/README.md#threshold)). If your request is under 1kb, it won't be compressed.

You can modify the threshold and set it to 0 bytes, if you want to.

```
app.use(compression({
  threshold: 0
}));
```

Comment: Ok cool. No it's fine for 1Kb. I just wanted to check if everything was working.